# Searchkick: suggestions when searching on multiple indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have two indices I want to search and return suggestions: Document and SharedDocument. With the sample below, I get blank suggestions when searching SharedDocument alone (expected) and 2 suggestions when searching Document (also expected). But when searching both at the same time, I get a blank result. Is this expected behaviour?

blank suggestions:

```
Searchkick.search('calculis', {index_name: [SharedDocument] , misspellings: false, suggest: [:name]}).suggestions
```

2 suggestions:

```
Searchkick.search('calculis', {index_name: [Document] , misspellings: false, suggest: [:name]}).suggestions
```

blank suggestions:

```
Searchkick.search('calculis', {index_name: [Document, SharedDocument] , misspellings: false, suggest: [:name]}).suggestions
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out issue was simply too few records in SharedDocument. Works as expected on larger datasets.